# How to parse JSON strings with argparse when executing the script with bash?

Tags: python, json, bash, argparse

I want to parse a JSON string given as an argument to the `argparse` module of a `python` script. The contents of the JSON string are defined in a `bash` file, which calls the `python` script. How should I escape the JSON string, so that it is properly parsed? So far, executing the `bash` script throws an `unrecognized arguments` error.

The `bash` file defines the `CONTENT` variable and executes the `python` script.

```bash
CONTENT='"{\"argument\": 5}"'
python script.py --content $CONTENT
```

The `python` script uses the `argparse` module to parse the string, but throws an error.

```py
import json
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--content", type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

content = json.loads(args.content)
print(f"Content: {content}")
```

Comment: Why do you have the extra double quotes surrounding the CONTENT string's JSON? `CONTENT='{\"argument\": 5}'` works with your script just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just correct the quoting in the shell script:

```
CONTENT='{"argument": 5}' 
python script.py --content "$CONTENT"
```